# Exclude .json file from a react build

Tags: reactjs

My React code builds a UI reading a JSON file. However, this file becomes a part of the `react build`. How can I keep this from minifying, and keep it as a separate file in a folder `'data/data.json'`. Right now I have a data folder inside `src`.

I want to be able to change the JSON file which will, in turn, change the UI.

Answer (score 2):

Fetch a request to get the file data instead of importing or requiring it.
example:

```
fetch(URL, {method:'GET'})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json=>{
        //use the json data
    })
```

If you are using redux, I suggest you to use the fetch request in your action and store data. If not, run the fetch request inside the componentDidMount and store data in your component state, which lets you pass data to children components.

Comment: What I would like to add to this answer is that you could reference files that are on the same site using a dot reference like this ``` (async () => {
  const url_redirect = "./db.json";
  const db = await fetch(url_redirect);
  const content = db.status >= 200 && db.status < 300 ? await db.json() : "";
  console.log(content);
})();```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Webpack to configure build settings if you haven't yet. You can use this [tutorial](https://www.robinwieruch.de/minimal-react-webpack-babel-setup/) on how to install it.

Install Copy Webpack Plugin: `npm i --save copy-webpack-plugin`

Go to the project's `webpack.config.prod.js` and `webpack.config.dev.js` (If you run build in development mode), use this configuration for an example of `src/assets/example.json`

```
    import CopyWebpackPlugin from 'copy-webpack-plugin';

    export default {
      plugins: [
         new CopyWebpackPlugin([
           { from: 'src/assets/example.json', to: 'assets/example.json' }]
         )
      ]
    }
```

This configuration extracts the JSON file from the `src` folder and prevents it from being minimized.